# Helping low rep users, and chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

A few times now (it is about to happen again), I have been trying to help a low rep user-- usually rep 1 or so-- with a problem and am getting nowhere in the comments. The comment form starts to complain about conversation in the comments and offers to move the discussion to chat. I'd love to do that but due to the rep of the other user, I can't.

Is there any way to add a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) that would allow a moderate rep user-- say 2000+, 3000+, or so-- to pull a low rep user into chat, and limit that low rank user to that one discussion? Sort of "guest access" to the chat rooms?

I think that a user only needs 20 rep to chat, which isn't much. Still, I have encountered this issue about 6 times in three months so I doubt that it is an uncommon occurrence.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat

Comment: I swear I searched for that thread before posting o_0. Thanks toscho.